# teach cout to handle null pointers gracefully

Tags: c++, cout, null-pointer

In my program I handle c style strings (of type char *) that are somtimes NULL. I would like to teach cout to handle those gracefully (i.e. to print "(null)" instead of segfaulting).

My first attempt:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const char *p_str) {
    if (p_str == nullptr)
        out << "(null)";
    else
        out << p_str;
    return out;
}
```

Does not work because it leads to an infinite recursion (in both if and else clause).
Two questions:

1. I can break the infinite recursion by calling the original `operator<<` from my redefined version. How do I do this? (lacking C++ skills here...)
2. Is there a better (more idiomatic) way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You need to either wrap the stream or the value, imho.

Comment: can one overload the `operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)` (within the rules of C++)?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz What makes you think so?

Comment: Idiomatic, write a function: `std::cout << null_format(p_str);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original output operators for strings are non-members defined in `namespace std` as

```
namespace std {
  template< class CharT, class Traits >
  basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&, const CharT*);

  template< class CharT, class Traits >
  basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&, const char*);

  template< class Traits> 
  basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,Traits>&, const char*);

  template< class Traits >
  basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,Traits>&, const signed char*);

  template< class Traits >
  basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,Traits>&, const unsigned char*);
}
```

and are found by [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). But you can, of course, call them explicitly as in (recall that `std::ostream` is merely a typedef to `std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>`)

```
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const char *p_str)
{  
  return std::operator<< (out, p_str==nullptr? "(null)" : p_str);
}
```

Overloading these operators in the global namespace is possible (though I'm not sure this is allowed by the standard), though I'd do this inside the namespace from which you're using them.

Comment: It's technically undefined behaviour to overload operators in `namespace std`, you can only specialize in `std`. It should be OK to overload them in the global namespace.

Comment: @vsoftco I don't quite get your point. I was not proposing to add anything to `namespace std`.

Comment: I was just saying that your code is fine (responding to the last sentence in your answer: *though I'm not sure this is allowed by the standard*), unless you decide to overload in `namespace std`, which you don't.

Comment: Would love to accept both answers. However I went with this one. Also, thanks for pointing to [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com)!

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution is to use [`std::basic_ostream<>::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) member function instead

```
if (p_str == nullptr)
    out.write("(null)", 6);
else
    out.write(p_str, std::strlen(p_str)); // need to #include <cstring> for std::strlen
return out;
```